# Wordpress Oceanwp happen or not in my website

Tags: wordpress-theming

If I use free ocean wp theme in my commercial website then any copyright will be happen or not.
P

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am getting your question right. What I understand is the following:

You want to use a Theme which is freely available via WP Theme repository in your WordPress Website.
This is the desired theme: https://de.wordpress.org/themes/oceanwp/

The Theme supports WooCommerce as described under above link.

My answer:
you may use any theme which can be found in WP theme repository on your WordPress website.

Best
Saskia